# Multi site not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, cpanel

I have site A which is the main site and site B which is multi site of Site A.

I have a problem where some things are not changing on site B eg the store phone number.  So I have changed the store phone number in store B in admin, and I have flushed cache and storage cache.  But the number is not changing ( note its a different number from store A and so the old number is not stored anywhere that I can see.)  I have looked into the code that calls the store number which is

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone'); ?>
```

I looked that up in the database and its showing the correct number ( and can't see the old number that still showing anywhere).

Another extension seems to have the same problem  and it seems to be related to `getStoreConfig`as other parts of the site B are updating ok (eg CMS changes are showing ok).

I'm using Firefox with local cache and cookies disabled

Is data for Site B cached somewhere else?

Magento 1.9, Nginx, xcache,

Thanks

Comment: When you say "Somethings are not changing" does that mean Somethings are changing?

Comment: yes things like changes in the CMS and stock levels are fine, but setting for the phone number, payment methods, geoip are not changing on site B but updating on Site A ( the main site) ok.  It does not look like values like phone number are not stored in cache as I can see changes in site A with out flushing cache,  but site B must be getting the old value from somewhere

Comment: I found out the cause of the problem.  It seems that Site B did not have premission to write to the cache folder that was on site A, If that happens its seems magento automaticly stores them in /tmp/magento/var/cache on the server,  Which was never being flushed.